# How to use nuxt plugin in another file?

Tags: nuxt.js, cryptojs

I have 2 files in plugins folder

`helper.js` and `cryptojs.js`

in cryptojs.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCryptojs from 'vue-cryptojs'

Vue.use(VueCryptojs)
```

in helper.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const encrypt = (str) => {
   // how to use VueCryptojs plugin here ?
}

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
       encrypt: encrypt 
    }
}
```

How to use VueCryptojs plugin in helper file? thanks

Comment: change the method to a function, not arrows, then uses this.$CryptoJS, as shown in docs, though why not ditch the vue-cryptojs and just use cryptojs?, its not like it adds anything.

Comment: thank you @LawrenceCherone, I didn't think about it, thank you so much